# Optimization in nested MySQL query possible?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table (simplified, removed unneeded columns):

**packageTransactions**

```
| memberID  |  subscriptionType |
| ==========|===================|
| 12345     |  101              |
| 12345     |  203              |
| 12346     |  101              |
| 12347     |  101              |
| 12348     |  101              |
| 12348     |  203              |
| 12349     |  203              |
| 12345     |  205              |
```

I want to query all records which have **not** `subscriptionType` = 101, **but only** those where a record for `subscriptionType` = 101 for the same `memberID` exists.

Therefore, I use:

```
SELECT memberID, subscriptionType
  FROM packageTransactions
 WHERE memberID IN
    ( SELECT memberID
        FROM packageTransactions
       WHERE subscriptionType = '101'
    )
   AND subscriptionType <> '101'
;
```

which gives me the resultset that I'm looking for:

```
| memberID  |  subscriptionType |
| ==========|===================|
| 12345     |  203              |
| 12348     |  203              |
| 12345     |  205              |
```

However, when using this query on a table with a few thousend records (+30k in my case), it takes minutes to return the result.

So I wonder, if there's a *"better"* / more efficient way to query the data?

Comment: SELECT memberID, subscriptionType  FROM packageTransactions WHERE subscriptionType != '101'. Did you try this why are you using where in?

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language. I tried to made it more clear in the question now. Because I want to get only those `memberID`s, where also a record for `subscriptionType` = '101' generally exists. memberID 12349 for example should **not** be returned, because it has no record for `subscriptionType` = '101'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT pt2.memberID, pt2.subscriptionType
FROM packageTransactions pt1 inner join packageTransactions pt2 
   ON pt1.memberID = pt2.memberID  
WHERE 
  pt1.subscriptionType = '101' AND pt2.subscriptionType <> '101'

;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb0cf/1)

```
select t.* from packageTransactions t
join
(
  select distinct memberID 
    from packageTransactions
  where subscriptionType = 101 
) t1 on t.memberId= t1.memberId
where
  (subscriptionType <> 101)
```

Comment: Thank you. Both, yours and Omar's, solutions are significant faster. However, now I wonder which query is more suitable and - even more important to me - why?